# Pairwise column operations (such as dot product) with a PySpark Dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Apologies but I'm new to Spark and this does not seem like a trivial operation to pull off.

If I have a PySpark Dataframe like so:

```
    +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
    |  id |  A  |  B  | ... |  N  |
    +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
    |  0  | 0.1 | 0.5 | ... | 0.9 |
    |  1  | 0.2 | 0.2 | ... | 0.1 |
    |  2  | 0.4 | 0.4 | ... | 0.3 |
    |  3  | 0.7 | 0.2 | ... | 0.2 |
    +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

and I want to run a pairwise (column) operation like a dot product *over all column combinations* of the Dataframe's columns, how do I go about it?

What I want is a Dataframe such as this one:

```
+-------+--------+-------+
|  n_1  |  n_2   |  dot  |
+-------+--------+-------+
|   A   |   A    |  1.3  | 
|   A   |   B    |  1.9  |
|   A   |   C    |  3.6  |
|   A   |   D    |  0.7  |
...
|   B   |   A    |  4.6  |
...
+-------+--------+-------+
```

which holds every combination of the N x N column products and their corresponding dot products.

Just for the record, I have around 1800 columns (N), and up to a few million ids.

Thank you!

Update: I made a mistake above. Now I've clarified that I want the column products, not row products.

Answer (score 2):

### Edit

To calculate the combinations between all columns as you described in your update, 
you can first multiply each column with all the others and aggregate with sum.

The result columns are named `X_Y = sum(x*y)`. And after this, you just need to transpose the result DataFrame. The following example is based on the same data as the first answer:

```
# get all possible combinations and calculate dot product
products = list()
for c in df.columns:
    if c != 'ID':
        for c2 in df.columns:
            if c2 != 'ID':
                products.append(sum(col(c) * col(c2)).alias(f"{c}_{c2}"))

dot_sums = df.select(*products)

# transpose columns to rows
col_values = explode(
    array(*[struct(lit(c).alias("col_name"), col(c).alias("val")) for c in dot_sums.columns])
).alias("cols_values")

# split the column name to get back the original columns
dot_sums.select(col_values) \
    .select(*[split(col("cols_values.col_name"), "_").getItem(0).alias("n_1"),
              split(col("cols_values.col_name"), "_").getItem(1).alias("n_2"),
              col("cols_values.val").alias("dot")]) \
    .show()

+---+---+------------------+
|n_1|n_2|               dot|
+---+---+------------------+
|  A|  A|               0.7|
|  A|  B|              0.39|
|  A|  C|              0.37|
|  B|  A|              0.39|
|  B|  B|0.4900000000000001|
|  B|  C|0.6300000000000001|
|  C|  A|              0.37|
|  C|  B|0.6300000000000001|
|  C|  C|0.9500000000000001|
+---+---+------------------+
```

### Original answer

A possible approach is to get all the combinations of `id_1 <-> id_2` columns by using `crossJoin`. 
And you can put all the other columns `A to N` in an array so that you could calculate the dot product later.

In addition to the following solution, you might want to have a look at [`mlib dot`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector.dot) function.

Here is an example:

```
data = [(0, 0.1, 0.5, 0.9), (1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1),
        (2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3), (3, 0.7, 0.2, 0.2)
        ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["ID", "A", "B", "C"])
df.show()

# get all cols except the ID col
op_cols = [c for c in df.columns if c != 'ID']

# transform those cols to array
df1 = df.select(col("ID").alias("ID_1"), array(*op_cols).alias("other_cols_array1"))
df2 = df.select(col("ID").alias("ID_2"), array(*op_cols).alias("other_cols_array2"))

# crossJoin
matrix = df1.crossJoin(df2)
```

Now, you have a DataFrame `matrix` with columns `ID_1`, `other_cols_array1`, `ID_2`, `other_cols_array2`.

So you can calculate the dot product for each combination `ID_1 - ID_2` using UDF like this:

```
dot_product = udf(lambda v1, v2: sum([x*y for x, y in zip(v1, v2)]), DoubleType())

matrix.withColumn("dot", dot_product(col("other_cols_array1"), col("other_cols_array2")))\
      .select("ID_1", "ID_2", "dot")\
      .show()
```

Comment: Apologies, I made a mistake above which I clarified now: I want vertical (column) dot products, not row products. The IDs in the first column of the original dataframe will be lost because the dot product will sum across them. Not sure yet if I will have to take this into account to make your solution work.

Comment: @KristianD'Amato I'm not sure I understand your update. Can you add a small example with few columns and the desired output please ?

Comment: I have just done so. Please see the second dataframe in the OP. The IDs are `A`, `B`, etc., where originally I had `0...3` which was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider only the data (i.e. without the row and col headers), it can be done in three lines with `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
dot = np.dot(a,np.transpose(a))
idx = np.triu_indices(len(a))
out = np.array([idx[0],idx[1],dot[idx]]).T

print(out)
```

gives:

```
[[  0   0  14]
 [  0   1  32]
 [  0   2  50]
 [  0   3  68]
 [  1   1  77]
 [  1   2 122]
 [  1   3 167]
 [  2   2 194]
 [  2   3 266]
 [  3   3 365]]
```

And of course, converting PySpark DF to/from Numpy array is trivial...

Comment: This would have been a very clever solution if only it worked in memory - I would have preferred numpy/pandas over PySpark if memory was not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

In pyspark it is a bit less elegant than in scala. Yet, it is totally achievable even in a generic way (it will work without assuming that we know the number of columns and their names).

What we can do is a Cartesian product of the dataframe with itself (`crossJoin`) and then computing the dot product with a map/reduce scheme.

Here is how I would do it:

```py
# creating sample data
data = [(0, .1, .5, .9), (1, .2, .2, .1), (2, .4, .4, .3), (3, .7, .2, .2)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['id', 'A', 'B', 'C'])

# all the columns but 'id'
cols = [c for c in df.columns if c != 'id']

# the same df with column names suffixed with '_2'
df2 = df.select(*[df[c].alias(c + '_2') for c in df.columns])

# the dot product
products = [F.col(c) * F.col(c+'_2') for c in cols]
dot_product = reduce(lambda a, b: a+b, products).alias('dot')

# and the cross join
df.crossJoin(df2).select(F.col('id'), F.col('id_2'), dot_product).show()
```

```
+---+----+-------------------+                                                  
| id|id_2|                dot|
+---+----+-------------------+
|  0|   0|               1.07|
|  0|   1|0.21000000000000002|
|  0|   2|               0.51|
|  0|   3|               0.35|
|  1|   0|0.21000000000000002|
|  1|   1|0.09000000000000002|
|  1|   2|0.19000000000000003|
|  1|   3|                0.2|
|  2|   0|               0.51|
|  2|   1|0.19000000000000003|
....
```

Comment: Apologies, I made a mistake above which I clarified now: I want vertical (column) dot products, not row products. The IDs in the first column of the original dataframe will be lost because the dot product will sum across them. Not sure yet if I will have to take this into account to make your solution work.

Comment: Could you provide sample data (enough to understand what you want to do, not more) and expected output so that we can verify our solution?

Comment: I corrected the second dataframe in the original post to reflect the clarification. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to compute the dot product of each column with each other column and itself.

One solution would be to start by computing, for each row i, one column for each combination of `col[j]*col[k]` for all `k` and `j`. If you have thousands of columns, this is something that I do not recommend for Spark SQL tends to struggle with that many columns.

What I would do it start by exploding the dataframe and create one row per id and column name. Then I would join the dataframe with itself based on the id. This would result in a dataframe with one row per id and per combination of two column names.

Finally, I would multiply the values of the two columns, group by the two column names, sum the values to obtain the dot product.

The code would look like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [(0, .1, .5, .9), (1, .2, .2, .1), (2, .4, .4, .3), (3, .7, .2, .2)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['id', 'A', 'B', 'C'])
cols = [c for c in df.columns if c != 'id']

flat_df = df.select(F.col('id'),
          F.explode(F.array(*[F.struct(F.lit(c).alias('name'),
                                       F.col(c).alias('value')) for c in cols])))
```

The first part is done, the data has been flatten like this:

```
>>> flat_df.show()
+---+-------+
| id|    col|
+---+-------+
|  0|[A,0.1]|
|  0|[B,0.5]|
|  0|[C,0.9]|
|  1|[A,0.2]|
|  1|[B,0.2]|
|  1|[C,0.1]|
|  2|[A,0.4]|
|  2|[B,0.4]|
|  2|[C,0.3]|
|  3|[A,0.7]|
|  3|[B,0.2]|
|  3|[C,0.2]|
+---+-------+
```

Then the second part: joining, multiplying, grouping and summing:

```py
flat_df_2 = flat_df.select('id',
                           F.col('col.name').alias('name2'),
                           F.col('col.value').alias('value2'))
result = flat_df\
    .join(flat_df_2, ['id'])\
    .withColumn('m', F.col('col.value') * F.col('value2'))\
    .groupBy(F.col('col.name').alias('n_1'), F.col('name2').alias('n_2'))\
    .agg(F.sum('m').alias('dot'))
```

which yields:

```
>>> result.show()
+---+---+------------------+
|n_1|n_2|               dot|
+---+---+------------------+
|  B|  C|              0.63|
|  A|  A|               0.7|
|  A|  C|              0.37|
|  C|  B|              0.63|
|  C|  C|0.9500000000000001|
|  C|  A|              0.37|
|  B|  B|0.4900000000000001|
|  B|  A|              0.39|
|  A|  B|              0.39|
+---+---+------------------+
```